# Pass variable to inside of keyup event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't seem to get a variable value in the following scenario:

```
function DoSomething(e) {
    console.log(e.data); // the data I want - outputs fine

    $(this).children('input').on('blur keyup', function(event) {
        if(event.keyCode == '13') {
            console.log(e.data); // the data is undefined for some reason?
        }

    }
}
```

e.data shows as undefined. How can I pass e.data to within the keyup event?

Comment: What is `e`? Do you have nested event handlers?

Comment: e is a MouseEvent. What do you mean by nested event handlers?

Comment: Capture the value to a variable to lock the value in.

Comment: Since DoSomething receives e, it only be valid in the function scope. You're defining an event for the keyup event, which is out of the scope of the function, therefore, e doesn't exist there.

Comment: Avoid binding handlers in other event handlers. You will have several handlers for each element.

Comment: @Malk: I already tried that. It doesn't seem to work?

Comment: Try `var e = $.extend({}, e.data)`

Comment: @Malk: That worked! Thanks! Can you explain what you did? I did use, var e = $.extend({}, e); however.

Comment: Objects are passed by reference so unless you pull the relevant data to a new object it will keep on returning to the event object. Extend just creates a new object and copies all the properties into it.

Comment: If you provide the answer below, I'll choose yours as the correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should save the value inside the DoSomehting scope

```
function DoSomething(e) {
    console.log(e.data); // the data you want - outputs fine
    var e = $.extend({}, e); // credits to @Malk

    $(this).children('input').on('blur keyup', function(event) {
        if(event.keyCode == '13') {
            console.log($e.data);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: $e.data is still undefined.

Comment: I see the comments from @Malk. Updated code to reflect those changes. All credits to [@Malk](http://stackoverflow.com/users/575199/malk)

Answer (score 1):

As they are nested event handlers. blur/keyup event inside MouseEvent, if you want to use the e.data inside the blur event you may need to store it in a variable.

In that case, lexical scope is formed (closure) and so keyup callback function will have access to the variable.

```
function DoSomething(e) {
    console.log(e.data); // the data I want - outputs fine
    var eventData = e.data; // store it in a variable so that it will be included in  lexical scope 

    $(this).children('input').on('blur keyup', function(event) {
        if(event.keyCode == '13') {
            console.log(eventData); 
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Actually event callback anyway has access to `e.data`, there is a closure anyway. So one more var is not needed. I would say, that the issue here is that event is bound inside other event..

Comment: Ya true. But I guess only the event is getting registered during mouseEvent. It's not fired. So the state of e will be lost.

Comment: @dfsq Sorry, yes you're right. It's available in closure.

Answer (score 0):

The first 'e' is declared for it's function, but the second one is not, since it's another function. You can declare a variable as global (outside a function, something like 'var x;') and use it.

My suggestion:

```
var x;
function DoSomething(e) {
    x = e;
    console.log(e.data);

    $(this).children('input').on('blur keyup', function(event) {
        if(event.keyCode == '13') {
            console.log(x.data);
        }
    }
}
```